# android view listview dialog inside a dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog, a dialog inside a dialog.
What I want is to display the results of dynamic `ListView` in my first dialog and in that first dialog theres a button to call the second dialog that contains `EditText` so that a new value of dynamic `ListView` can be inserted and view it the first dialog.

```
public void dialoListview() {
    final Dialog rankDialog = new Dialog(HI_Talk.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    rankDialog.setContentView(R.layout.listview_sample);
    rankDialog.setCancelable(true);
    ImageButton app_icon = (ImageButton) rankDialog.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> savednotes_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(savednotes_adapter);

    app_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promt = li.inflate(R.layout.savednotes_list, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alerDialogBuilder.setView(promt);

            final EditText textfield_savednotes = (EditText) promt.findViewById(R.id.edt_textfield);
            alerDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("saved", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    String temp_name = textfield_savednotes.getText().toString();
                    arrayList.add(textfield_savednotes.getText().toString());
                    textfield_savednotes.setText("");
                    savednotes_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Template Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alerDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    rankDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: can you tell what error are you getting

Comment: unfortunately, hi_chat has stop thats the error, hi_chat is the activity name...

Comment: list.setAdapter(savednotes_adapter); f i comment this statement , no error but it wont display the text i entered to dialog1

Comment: follow below answer of sasikumar you need to remove final from ArrayList and ArrarAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  final  in arrayList,ArrayAdapter and declare as global in your activity

Before oncreate

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList;
 ArrayAdapter<String> savednotes_adapter;
```

inside oncreate or your method

```
 arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
 savednotes_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
```